# How Or Should I Add a Return To This Function?

Tags: php, function, return, refactoring

I am using JetBrain's PhpStorm and running their code inspector on some code I've inherited. One of the issues PhpStorm detects is "inconsistent return points" - in the following case it is a return statement that is missing entirely. I'm wondering if I should add a return statement to this function and if so how I would go about doing so.

```
 /**
 * Loads the view and outputs it
 *
 * @since  0.1.3
 *
 * @param  boolean $echo Whether to output or return the template
 *
 * @return string        Rendered template
 */
public function load( $echo = false ) {
    $content = '';

    // If we haven't done the template before (or we're forcing it)...
    if ( ! isset( self::$done[ $this->template ] ) || $this->force ) {
        // Then get the content.
        $content = parent::load( false );
    }

    // If we got content...
    if ( $content ) {

        $content = $this->format_css_tag( $content );

        // Ok, this one is done, don't load it again.
        self::$done[ $this->template ] = $this->template;
    }

    if ( ! $echo ) {
        return $content;
    }

    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: Functions should basically never echo anything generally, the data should always be returned to be echo'd later. I suggest just doing `return $content` instead of checking if `$echo` is set, get rid of that parameter as it is not necessary. If you don't want to echo it, simply echo it on page `echo load()`

Answer (score 1):

You could follow `print_r()` as a guide and if you echo the content out, just

```
return true;
```

to say the function has run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
public function load( $echo = false ) {
  $content = '';

  // If we haven't done the template before (or we're forcing it)...
  if ( ! isset( self::$done[ $this->template ] ) || $this->force ) {
    // Then get the content.
    $content = parent::load( false );
  }

  // If we got content...
  if ( $content ) {

    $content = $this->format_css_tag( $content );

    // Ok, this one is done, don't load it again.
    self::$done[ $this->template ] = $this->template;
  } else {
    $content = false;
  }

  return $content;
}
```

And then do the echo wherever this function got called.